# Making Pandas dataframe to display aggregate values based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, crosstab

Hello a Python newbie here.

I have a dataframe that shows the product and how much they sold on each date
[image]

I need to change this dataframe to show the aggregate amount of units sold.
[image]

This is just an example dataframe and the actual dataframe that I am dealing with contains hundreds of products and 3 years worth of sales data.

It would be appreciated if there would be a way to do this efficiently.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `product` is column use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) for cumulative sum:

```
df1 = df.set_index('product').cumsum(axis=1)
```

If product is `index`:

```
df1 = df.cumsum(axis=1)
```

Comment: @AdamLee Make sure to check that your columns are in chronological order, and sort them if they aren't (`.sort_index(axis=1)`).